# Can't extend extension added structs on swift

Tags: swift, struct, swift-extensions

I have `CustomClass` like so:

```
class CustomClass {
    let attribute: Int
}
```

In another file I've added it a `StructureA` via extension like so:

```
extension CustomClass {
    struct StructureA {
        let someData: Int
    }
}
```

In a third file, I'm attempting to extend my `CustomClass.StructureA` like this:

[image]

I don't get what's wrong about it. If I do the exact same implementation on the same file where I have the implementation of StructureA it works fine.

[image]

Any ideas on what I might be missing?

Comment: They support nested types, I just don't get why they're not extendable from another file 

Comment: The code itself is sound, so it looks like an access control issue. This isn't a solution, but try `open class CustomClass`, and possibly `open extension CustomClass`

Comment: This is a known bug: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-631

Comment: Neither the extension nor the struct can be define as `open` ...

Comment: Yeah, apparently it is a bug... That's bummer..  
Thanks @Hamish  

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @Hamish, turns out it's a known bug:

https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-631